# Python - Regex findall repeated pattern followed by variable length of chars

Tags: python, regex

I have the following pattern:
`1MHG161  xxxxxxxxxxxxx  1MHG161 xxx` 
where `xxxx` is variable length of chars & spaces.

I am trying to capture each one and have the following expected output: 
`[ '1MHG161  xxxxxxxxxxxxx  ' , '1MHG161 xxx' ]`

I have tried a lot of combination this is the last one

```
messages_strings = re.findall("(1MHG161.+?)(?=1MHG161)",content)
```

This finds all except the last one.

---

#### Edit 1:

I have taken @anubhava answer, a little bit further to solve the same problem but with dynamic delimiters by using  `\d[A-Z]{3}\d{3}` instead of `1MHG161`

This may help people working with EDI parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(1MHG161.+?)(?=1MHG161|$)", content)
['1MHG161  xxxxxxxxxxxxx  ', '1MHG161 xxx']
```

Lookahead `(?=1MHG161|$)` will match `1MHG161` or end of line anchor `$` after your match.